# Master-detail: How to fetch a control from a template inside the "detail" ContentControl?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, master-detail

I have a `ListView` (on the 'master' side) whose selection drives a `ContentControl`'s `Content` property (on the 'detail' side). The `ContentControl`'s visual tree comes from either of two `DataTemplate` resources that use `DataType` to choose which detail view to render based on what is selected in the `ListView`.
That part works fine.

The part I'm struggling with is that there is a particular control *inside* (one of) the templates that I need to obtain a reference to whenever it changes (e.g. the template selected changes or the `ListView` selection changes such that the instance of the control is recreated.)

In my `ListView.SelectionChanged` event handler, I find the `ContentControl` has not yet been updated with its new visual tree, so initially it's empty on the first selection, and for subsequent selections its visual tree matches the *old* selection instead of the new one.
I've tried delaying my code by scheduling on the `Dispatcher` with a priority as low as `DispatcherPriority.Loaded`, which works for the first selection but on subsequent selections my code still runs before the visual tree is updated.

Is there a better event I should be hooking to run whenever the `ContentControl`'s visual tree is changed to reflect a changed data-bound value to its `Content` property?

Extra info: the reason I need to reach into the expanded `DataTemplate` is that I need to effectively set my view model's `IList SelectedItems` property to a `DataGrid` control's `SelectedItems` property. Since `DataGrid.SelectedItems` is not a dependency property, I have to do this manually in code.

Comment: This is where the close votes were registered : Needs debugging details (2 votes)
The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The fix required a combination of techniques. For the first selection that populates the visual tree, I needed to handle `ContentControl.OnApplyTemplate()` which is only a virtual method rather than an event. I derived from it and exposed it as an event:

```cs
public class ContentControlWithEvents : ContentControl
{
    public event EventHandler? TemplateApplied;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        this.TemplateApplied?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

In the XAML I used the above class rather than `ContentControl`:

```xml
<local:ContentControlWithEvents
   Content="{Binding SelectedAccount}"
   x:Name="BankingSelectedAccountPresenter" 
   TemplateApplied="BankingSelectedAccountPresenter_TemplateApplied" />
```

Then I handle the event like this:

```cs
void BankingSelectedAccountPresenter_TemplateApplied(object sender, EventArgs e) => this.UpdateSelectedTransactions();

private void UpdateSelectedTransactions()
{
    if (this.MyListView.SelectedItem?.GetType() is Type type)
    {
        DataTemplateKey key = new(type);
        var accountTemplate = (DataTemplate?)this.FindResource(key);
        Assumes.NotNull(accountTemplate);
        if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(this.BankingSelectedAccountPresenter) > 0)
        {
            ContentPresenter? presenter = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this.BankingSelectedAccountPresenter, 0) as ContentPresenter;
            Assumes.NotNull(presenter);
            presenter.ApplyTemplate();
            var transactionDataGrid = (DataGrid?)accountTemplate.FindName("TransactionDataGrid", presenter);
            this.ViewModel.Document.SelectedTransactions = transactionDataGrid?.SelectedItems;
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `GetChildrenCount` check that avoids an exception thrown from `GetChild` later if there are no children yet. We'll need that for later.

The `TemplateApplied` event is raised only once -- when the `ContentControl` is first given its `ContentPresenter` child. We still the `UpdateSelectedTransactions` method to run when the ListView in the 'master' part of the view changes selection:

```cs
void BankingPanelAccountList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) => this.UpdateSelectedTransactions();
```

On initial startup, `SelectionChanged` is raised first, and we skip this one with the `GetChildrenCount` check. Then `TemplateApplied` is raised and we use the current selection to find the right template and search for the control we need. Later when the selection changes, the first event is raised again and re-triggers our logic.

The last trick is we must call `ContentPresenter.ApplyTemplate()` to force the template selection to be updated *before* we search for the child control. Without that, this code may still run before the template is updated based on the type of item selected in the `ListView`.